# How to rotate Bitmap in windows GDI?

Tags: c++, gdi

How would I go about rotating a Bitmap in Windows GDI,C++?

Comment: What kind of rotation? 90 deg increments, arbitrary increments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with GDI+ (`#include <gdiplus.h>`).  The Graphics class has the [RotateTransform method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535805%28VS.85%29.aspx).  That allows arbitrary rotations.  Use [Image::RotateFlip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535401%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you only need to rotate by 90 degree increments, that's a lot more efficient.

Comment: @Frank Krueger - you have to be able to mind-read on this site. Either that, or throw pasta at the wall and see what sticks.

Comment: Better stick with raw GDI+ implementation as RotateFlip is infamous for throwing out the 'Generic GDI+ error occured' exception quite often.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have to use [PlgBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162804(VS.85).aspx). Take your rectangle's 4 corners as 2D Points, rotate them, then call PlgBlt.

From [MSDN Bitmap Rotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183389(VS.85).aspx):

> To copy a bitmap into
>   a parallelogram; use the PlgBlt
>   function, which performs a bit-block
>   transfer from a rectangle in a source
>   device context into a parallelogram in
>   a destination device context. To
>   rotate the bitmap, an application must
>   provide the coordinates, in world
>   units, to be used for the corners of
>   the parallelogram.

Comment: The PlgBlt docs specifically mention that rotation transformations are not supported.  That's accurate.  Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162804%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility (beyond those already suggested) is to use `SetWorldTransform()`. This is different in that it is modal and applies to the DC as a whole, not just a single operation. If you want to rotate one bitmap rotated, but other things without rotation, it's probably not your best choice. If you want to draw a number of things rotated, or (especially) if you want to rotate everything you draw (at least into one DC) it can work quite nicely though.

Comment: I tried SetWorldTransform () and it had absolutely no effect.  The documentation says that the device context's graphics mode must be set to GM_ADVANCED.  I tried it, and it resulted in a totally black bitmap.

This is what usually happens when trying a Microsoft feature; it doesn't work, and you spend the other 90% of your time trying to figure out why.  .NET is noticeably better, but it's so slow.